# Facebook page Album in ios app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, fbconnect

i have a Facebook page, and i want to fetch all the photo albums of the FB Page to an ios application am currently developing. 
I seem to have stuck at it.

Please someone suggest how i should go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use graph APi to get all the details from your Facebook page.....

https://graph.facebook.com/ID/albums

returns list from your page.

Comment: replace the ID with your page ID